# Best Searching Technique for large number of possibilities

Tags: algorithm, search, set

I'm trying to search text file for large number of possibilites.

for example, I want to search a text file that contains unique names. 
now, if I found name X then I want to store X in another file.

the problem here I have over 1000 unique names, and I dont want to do 1000 search calls and if statements for each unique name.

is there any better way of doing that in java/javascript/php ?

Comment: are they delimited somehow? comma, space, new line? if so you can get the contents, explode it, put it in an array, run array_unique() and have a list of unique names.  Then run something to iterate over and create new text files for each.

Comment: [MapReduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) is your friend.

Comment: no, they are more like between the lines. for example : john is going somewhere with mike. and I need to find "john" and "mike". then store them in another file

Comment: In what language? You aren't coding this in Java, PHP and JavaScript? Please don't tag meaninglessly to get more attention to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a Set of names and you want to find which names match another Set of names.

```
Set<String> namesFromFile = readFile(filename);
Set<String> namesToMatch = readFile(matchingNames);
namesToMatch.retainAll(namedFromFile);
```

The `retainAll` is an O(n) operation where `n` is the size of the smaller set. In Java a `retainAll` of a set of 1000 values can take a few milli-seconds.

[Set.retainAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29) does the following

> Retains only the elements in this set that are contained in the specified collection (optional operation). In other words, removes from this set all of its elements that are not contained in the specified collection. If the specified collection is also a set, this operation effectively modifies this set so that its value is the intersection of the two sets.

---

A set of 1000 is so small its difficult to test accurately so in this test I test one 10x larger, i.e. 10,000 element against a set of 100,000 elements.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    Set<String> names1 = generateStrings(100000, 2);
    Set<String> names2 = generateStrings(10000, 3);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        Set<String> intersect= new HashSet<String>(names2);
        intersect.retainAll(names1);
        long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
        System.out.printf("The intersect of %,d and %,d elements has %,d and took %.3f ms%n",
                names1.size(), names2.size(), intersect.size(), time / 1e6);
    }
}

private static Set<String> generateStrings(int number, int multiple) {
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        set.add(Integer.toBinaryString(i * multiple));
    return set;
}
```

prints

```
The intersect of 100,000 and 10,000 elements has 5,000 and took 21.173 ms
The intersect of 100,000 and 10,000 elements has 5,000 and took 10.785 ms
The intersect of 100,000 and 10,000 elements has 5,000 and took 9.597 ms
The intersect of 100,000 and 10,000 elements has 5,000 and took 3.414 ms
The intersect of 100,000 and 10,000 elements has 5,000 and took 2.791 ms
The intersect of 100,000 and 10,000 elements has 5,000 and took 2.629 ms
The intersect of 100,000 and 10,000 elements has 5,000 and took 2.689 ms
The intersect of 100,000 and 10,000 elements has 5,000 and took 2.753 ms
The intersect of 100,000 and 10,000 elements has 5,000 and took 2.704 ms
The intersect of 100,000 and 10,000 elements has 5,000 and took 2.645 ms
```

Comment: is it possible to know what names are matched ? i mean if i have john, mike, nancy and only john and mike matched, is it possible to know that?

Comment: I'm just trying to understand here. so sorry if it may sound stupid.
retainAll will return true or false if the two lists match right?

Comment: i.e. where i can find what names are matched will this be saved in namesToMatch?

Comment: I have added a benchmark for a set 10x larger to give you an idea of speed.

Comment: According to the Javadoc it modifies the first set to "retail all" the elements which are also in the second set.

Comment: Technically, it deletes the elements which are not also in the second set.